# How to keep a certain part of border above the content of a child div?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to keep a custom shape of a container (the parent div) to not change when the posts (the child div), are scrolled up.

[This is what it's supposed to look like all the time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szWzf.png)

[This is what it looks like when the posts are scrolled up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Pmb.png)

I'd like the cut off corner to stay that way. I've tried using z-index for each element, but that doesn't seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
#container {
  background: {
    color: background
  }
  ;
  width: 400px;
  height: 435px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 12;
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

#container:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 70px solid {
    color: border
  }
  ;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute
}

#border {
  background: {
    color: border
  }
  ;
  width: 450px;
  height: 490px;
  margin-left: 800px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

#border:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 60px solid {
    color: background
  }
  ;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

.posts {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>{Title}</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}"> {block:Description}
  <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" /> {/block:Description}

  <meta name="color:background" content="#FFFFFF" />
  <meta name="color:border" content="#000000" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="border">
    <div id="container">
      {block:Posts}
      <div class="posts">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: All I can see of your demo are the words `{block:Description} {/block:Description}`. This bears no relation at all to the images you've shared.

Comment: Could you give us more information about what you need - your description isn't clear